# NSToolbarItem: Size button to fit / set content hugging priority

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsbutton, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I'm trying to make an `NSToolbarItem` containing an `NSButton` fit the button's width. However, when I set the toolbar item's max width to a high value (e.g. 300) and there is enough space in the toolbar, the button will always expand to the full 300 points.

How can I allow the button to grow to e.g. 300 points, but *only* if that is necessary to accommodate its contents (i.e. hug its content)? It seems like setting the buttons `contentHuggingPriority` is ignored if it is inside an `NSToolbar`.

Comment: Is the text of the button always the same?

Comment: No - then I could just fix the button's width.

Comment: Can't you adjust `maxSize` after changing the title?

Comment: I didn't think of that, thanks! On the other hand, the point of auto layout is to make computations like this automatic...

Comment: I would think so too. Did you ever figure out this madness?

Comment: I can't recall, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I made it for a `NSTextField`, but it should also work for a `NSButton`. You have to set this after changing the `stringValue` (set the `minSize` and `maxSize` to a low value in Xcode):

```
if let font = tf.font {
    let size = tf.stringValue.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font])
    toolBarItem.minSize.width = size.width    // maybe + x
}
```

Maybe you have to add some pixels to `size.width`, so that the button will be large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question.
Create 2 ib outlets

```
@IBOutlet weak var  toolBarRegistrationHint: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var  toolBarRegistrationHintItem: NSToolbarItem!
```

than in code

```
        var maxSize = toolBarRegistrationHintItem!.maxSize

        toolBarRegistrationHint!.title = "Pro ✔︎".localized
        toolBarRegistrationHint!.sizeToFit()
        maxSize.width = toolBarRegistrationHint!.frame.size.width
        toolBarRegistrationHintItem!.maxSize = maxSize
```

Answer (score -1):

You could accomplish what you want by changing border setting of the button as Off and set image's scaling option as proportionally Down.

Here is some examples. You could see the different result previews with the setting changes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am asking for. My button doesn't contain any images, but I want it to automatically become smaller when it contains text.

Comment: Even though the content may not visually take up as much space, the toolbar item will still occupy that space and prevent other items from occupying it.